# WebView downloads some files but others it doesn't

Tags: android, webview

I'm creating a simple android WebView app that loads a website that uses a lot of javascript.

Basically my issue is that some download links work and some others don't but all of them work on a mobile browser.
I don't have access to the websites code so I can't make any changes their.

So what I tried until now.

I add all the correct permissions.

```
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_WIFI_STATE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
```

and i implemented a setDownloadListener method onDonloadStart.

```
      WebView.setDownloadListener(new DownloadListener(){
        @Override
        public void onDownloadStart(String url, String userAgent,String contentDisposition, String mimetype,long contentLength)
        {
            Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW);
            Uri path = Uri.parse(url);
            DownloadManager.Request request = new DownloadManager.Request(path);

            request.setMimeType(mimetype);

            intent.setDataAndType(path,"application/pdf");
            intent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);
            intent.setData(path);
            startActivity(intent);
        }
    });
```

My Webview settings are:

```
    webSettings.setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
    webSettings.setJavaScriptCanOpenWindowsAutomatically(true);
    webSettings.setLoadsImagesAutomatically(true);
    webSettings.setAllowFileAccess(true);
    webSettings.setLoadWithOverviewMode(false);
    webSettings.setUseWideViewPort(false);
    webSettings.setSupportZoom(false);
    webSettings.setCacheMode(WebSettings.LOAD_CACHE_ELSE_NETWORK);

    WebView.setScrollBarStyle(View.SCROLLBARS_INSIDE_OVERLAY);
    WebView.canGoBack();
```

So does anyone have any idea why this is happening?

Comment: You did not tell what kind of links do not work. Should we guess?

Comment: The links are pdf files. I would like to download them or view them in mobile browser or webView.